# How to get the parameters when launch my app with url?

Tags: android, url, parameters, launch

I add a filter in Manifest to enable browser to launch my app, like this

```
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />

            <data
                android:host="test"
                android:scheme="myapp" />
        </intent-filter>
```

But I got the re-direction address with params:"myapp://test?param1=123&param2=456"

How can I open my app and get these parameters?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2958701/launch-custom-android-application-from-android-browser and check this https://developer.chrome.com/multidevice/android/intents

Answer (score 0):

We get the params as extras in our activitie's onCreate method.
To access it use :

getIntent().getExtras().getString("param1");